# I'm making a Minecraft Mod and I get the error "mods.toml missing metadata for modid mymod"

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Using Eclipse to try and make a test mod, been trying to get it to load up properly but it doesn't work.

Here is main:

```
@Mod("mymod")
public class mymod
{
public static final String MOD_ID = "mymod";

public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
public mymod() {
IEventBus bus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus():
MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
  }
}
```

Here is my mods.toml:

```
modLoader="javafml" #mandatory

loaderVersion="[35,)"


license="All rights reserved"



[[mods]] #mandatory

modId="mymod" #mandatory

version="${file.jarVersion}" #mandatory

displayName="test" #mandatory





description='''


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis lacinia magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed sagittis luctus odio eu tempus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque volutpat ligula eget lacus auctor sagittis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc gravida elit vitae sem vehicula efficitur. Donec mattis ipsum et arcu lobortis, eleifend sagittis sem rutrum. Cras pharetra quam eget posuere fermentum. Sed id tincidunt justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
'''

[[dependencies.mymod]] #optional
   
    modId="forge" #mandatory
   
    mandatory=true #mandatory
   
    versionRange="[35,)" #mandatory
   
    ordering="NONE"
   
    side="BOTH"

[[dependencies.mymod]]
    modId="minecraft"
    mandatory=true

    versionRange="[1.16.4,1.17)"
    ordering="NONE"
    side="BOTH"
```

Here is pack.mcmeta:

```
{
    "pack": {
        "description": "mymod resources",
        "pack_format": 6,
        "_comment": "A pack_format of 6 requires json lang files and some texture changes from 1.16.2. Note: we require v6 pack meta for all mods."
    }
}
```

Here is a crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't do that.

Time: 16/11/21 7:46 PM
Description: Mod loading error has occurred

java.lang.Exception: Mod Loading has failed
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender.dumpModLoadingCrashReport(CrashReportExtender.java:85) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.completeModLoading(ClientModLoader.java:188) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$null$1(Minecraft.java:513) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.util.Util.acceptOrElse(Util.java:323) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$new$2(Minecraft.java:509) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.ResourceLoadProgressGui.render(ResourceLoadProgressGui.java:113) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer.updateCameraAndRender(GameRenderer.java:492) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1002) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:612) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:184) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:52) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105) [forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {}


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender.lambda$dumpModLoadingCrashReport$7(CrashReportExtender.java:88) ~[forge:?] {re:classloading}
-- NO MOD INFO AVAILABLE --
Details:
    Mod File: NO FILE INFO
    Failure message: mods.toml missing metadata for modid mymod
    Mod Version: NO MOD INFO AVAILABLE
    Mod Issue URL: NOT PROVIDED
    Exception message: MISSING EXCEPTION MESSAGE
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender.lambda$dumpModLoadingCrashReport$7(CrashReportExtender.java:88) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender.dumpModLoadingCrashReport(CrashReportExtender.java:86) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.ClientModLoader.completeModLoading(ClientModLoader.java:188) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$null$1(Minecraft.java:513) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.util.Util.acceptOrElse(Util.java:323) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$new$2(Minecraft.java:509) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.ResourceLoadProgressGui.render(ResourceLoadProgressGui.java:113) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer.updateCameraAndRender(GameRenderer.java:492) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1002) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:612) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:184) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:52) ~[forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66) [modlauncher-8.0.6.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105) [forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-recomp.jar:?] {}


-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.16.4
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.16.4
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_302, Temurin
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Temurin
    Memory: 1379058664 bytes (1315 MB) / 1674575872 bytes (1597 MB) up to 3804758016 bytes (3628 MB)
    CPUs: 12
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
    ModLauncher: 8.0.6+85+master.325de55
    ModLauncher launch target: fmluserdevclient
    ModLauncher naming: mcp
    ModLauncher services: 
        /mixin-0.8.2.jar mixin PLUGINSERVICE 
        /eventbus-3.0.5-service.jar eventbus PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-launcher.jar object_holder_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-launcher.jar runtime_enum_extender PLUGINSERVICE 
        /accesstransformers-2.2.0-shadowed.jar accesstransformer PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-launcher.jar capability_inject_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-launcher.jar runtimedistcleaner PLUGINSERVICE 
        /mixin-0.8.2.jar mixin TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
        /forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.3-launcher.jar fml TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
    FML: 35.1
    Forge: net.minecraftforge:35.1.4
    FML Language Providers: 
        javafml@35.1
        minecraft@1
    Mod List: 
        client-extra.jar                                  |Minecraft                     |minecraft                     |1.16.4              |NONE      |a1:d4:5e:04:4f:d3:d6:e0:7b:37:97:cf:77:b0:de:ad:4a:47:ce:8c:96:49:5f:0a:cf:8c:ae:b2:6d:4b:8a:3f
        forge-1.16.4-35.1.4_mapped_snapshot_20201028-1.16.|Forge                         |forge                         |35.1.4              |NONE      |NOSIGNATURE
        main                                              |mymod                         |examplemod                    |NONE                |NONE      |NOSIGNATURE
```

The game also tries to load something called "examplemod" despite there not being anything called that in the code because I removed it. I can't even get to the title screen, however if I replace the Mod ID in mods.toml to "examplemod" the game will start up but I will get an error saying that it's missing metadata in mods.toml

I have it set to build automatically so I don't think it's a build problem. I would really appreciate the help, thank you so much!

Comment: Post your project tree.

Comment: @JustInCoding I'm not quite sure how to do that, new here. Do you need me to upload it to github and link it?

Comment: Yeah, a github repository would be awesome!

Comment: @JustInCoding Here it is https://github.com/DeviledBread/Stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed it. Turns out I had everything correct, just my MODID isn’t supposed to have CAPS. MODID is supposed to be all lowercase for some reason, anyways yeah.

Answer (score 0):

The mod jar on your client/server still seems to contain an invalid `mods.toml` file. Seeing the `examplemod` in your crash report validates this. This can have multiple causes:

- You simply forgot to move your mod jar to the client/server mods directory.
- Your gradle build falsely believes that your resources have not updated.
- You have multiple `mods.toml` files, and you are not editing the `META-INF/mods.toml` version, so your changes don't seem to apply (in older Forge versions, the mod descriptor file was placed elsewhere).

In either case, open your project directory in a command window and run `gradlew clean` followed by `gradlew build`. Then copy your mod jar over to the client/server and then start that client/server.

Comment: Where is the client/server mods directory?

Comment: I'm surprised by this question. It's the directory in which you put your mod jar file to use it on the client or server. For clients, this defaults to `%APPDATA%/Roaming/.minecraft/mods`, and for servers this is `<server root dir>/mods`.

Comment: I'm confused, I don't think we're on the same page. I don't see [%APPDATA%] where I'm looking. I ran the commands you told me to and I'm not sure if anything happened. I was using a tutorial I found on YouTube, I'm kinda new to working with eclipse in general. Here is the link to the video I used: https://youtu.be/benUZaQU-6Y

Comment: When you insert `%APPDATE%` in Windows Explorer, it links you to `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming`. The mods directories I talked about are where you have to place your mod jar to be able to add it to the client or server. You get the mod jar from building your project by running `gradlew build` in a command prompt at your project directory root. This will always give you feedback in the command prompt, whether it's a success or a failed build.

Comment: I did gradlew build and put the mod jar in \AppData\.minecraft\mods and it still crashes upon launch.

Comment: Did you also do a clean and checked the other points that I mentioned? If it still crashes on some "ExampleMod" occurrence then, try searching through all source files for that string (Notepad++ can do that in the ctrl+f menu). If it's not in the source code, then your clean didn't succeed or the problem is in another mod jar, which I mentioned in the answer already.

Comment: I fixed it, we were not on the same wavelength lol

Comment: Ah, good to hear that it's fixed. You can mark this question as accepted if you feel like it has helped with the problem by clicking the checkmark next to it.