# 'Missing mods.toml file' on a game crash log for a minecraft modpack

Tags: minecraft-forge

Sorry i'm newish to modding and this kind of thing generally, but i found a loosely related link on here which i've included below if that helps???

[I'm making a Minecraft Mod and I get the error "mods.toml missing metadata for modid mymod"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998825/im-making-a-minecraft-mod-and-i-get-the-error-mods-toml-missing-metadata-for-m/70163387#70163387?newreg=94c23ce47e1446df946a9fac4f23c6f5)

please also see my crash log at the very bottom of this field. the lines roughly halfway down the log starting in '[07:21:05] [main/WARN]:' appear to be the relevant ones, as well as the suffixes to these lines, which are 'is missing mods.toml file'.

i have very little clue what mods exactly these relate to, making it hard to contact the mod builders directly, so that's why i've come to stackoverflow to annoy you lot!

please ignore the below lines, i'm pretty sure this related to user error and i can muddle my way through a solution to it:

> [07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Found duplicate mods:
> Mod ID: 'rubidium' from mod files: rubidium-mc1.20.1-0.7.1a.jar, embeddium-0.3.4+mc1.20.1.jar
> [07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Failed to build unique mod list after mod discovery.

...i suppose that means you can also ignore the below one??

'[07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Mod Discovery failed. Skipping dependency discovery.'

could any of this be related to the fact that i'm playing on a computer with a 'split' hard drive? i.e. the main c: drive is not what i've downloaded any of these things to... they are stored, out of apparent necessity, on an additional hard drive (the D: drive as detailed in the opening lines of the below crash log), that was added to it post purchase. it is a shared computer with a lot of other games on the c drive i guess.

::::::::CRASH LOG::::::::

> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: ModLauncher running: args [--username, gapplepie1985, --version, forge-47.2.0, --gameDir, D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1, --assetsDir, D:\franes shiet\Install\assets, --assetIndex, 5, --uuid, 5d78a72ad85d45229642244218208177, --accessToken, ????????, --clientId, ZDY4YWQ5N2EtMjIzOS00YzdjLTk3MWEtZDBhMWI0NDI2NDQ5, --xuid, 2535447087133058, --userType, msa, --versionType, release, --width, 1024, --height, 768, --quickPlayPath, D:\franes shiet\Install\quickPlay\java\1708194063340.json, --launchTarget, forgeclient, --fml.forgeVersion, 47.2.0, --fml.mcVersion, 1.20.1, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.mcpVersion, 20230612.114412]
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: ModLauncher 10.0.9+10.0.9+main.dcd20f30 starting: java version 17.0.8 by Microsoft; OS Windows 11 arch amd64 version 10.0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Loading ImmediateWindowProvider fmlearlywindow
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Trying GL version 4.6
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Requested GL version 4.6 got version 4.6
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8.5 Source=union:/D:/franes%20shiet/Install/libraries/org/spongepowered/mixin/0.8.5/mixin-0.8.5.jar%23100!/ Service=ModLauncher Env=CLIENT
> [07:21:05] [pool-2-thread-1/INFO]: GL info: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 551.23, NVIDIA Corporation
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file architectury-9.1.13-forge.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file balm-forge-1.20.1-7.2.1.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file canary-mc1.20.1-0.3.3.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file cloth-config-11.1.118-forge.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file cookingforblockheads-forge-1.20-16.0.1.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file dynamiclightsreforged-1.20.1_v1.6.0.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file embeddium-0.3.4+mc1.20.1.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file ferritecore-6.0.1-forge.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file lazydfu-0.1.3.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file oculus-mc1.20.1-1.6.15a.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file pamhc2foodcore-1.20.4-1.0.5.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file REIPluginCompatibilities-forge-12.0.93.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file RoughlyEnoughItems-12.0.684-forge.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file rubidium-extra-0.5.4+mc1.20.1-build.116.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file rubidium-mc1.20.1-0.7.1a.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file saturn-mc1.20.1-0.1.3.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file starlight-1.1.2+forge.1cda73c.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file Terralith_1.20.4_v2.4.11.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file TextruesRubidiumOptions-1.0.5+mc1.20.1.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file TravelersBackpack-1.20.1-9.1.12.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file Xaeros_Minimap_23.9.7_Forge_1.20.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file XaerosWorldMap_1.37.8_Forge_1.20.jar of type MOD with provider {mods folder locator at D:\franes shiet\Instances\Create 1.20.1\mods}
> [07:21:05] [main/WARN]: Mod file D:\franes shiet\Install\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlcore\1.20.1-47.2.0\fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar is missing mods.toml file
> [07:21:05] [main/WARN]: Mod file D:\franes shiet\Install\libraries\net\minecraftforge\javafmllanguage\1.20.1-47.2.0\javafmllanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar is missing mods.toml file
> [07:21:05] [main/WARN]: Mod file D:\franes shiet\Install\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.20.1-47.2.0\lowcodelanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar is missing mods.toml file
> [07:21:05] [main/WARN]: Mod file D:\franes shiet\Install\libraries\net\minecraftforge\mclanguage\1.20.1-47.2.0\mclanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar is missing mods.toml file
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar of type LIBRARY with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file javafmllanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar of type LANGPROVIDER with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file lowcodelanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar of type LANGPROVIDER with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file mclanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar of type LANGPROVIDER with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file client-1.20.1-20230612.114412-srg.jar of type MOD with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/INFO]: Found mod file forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-universal.jar of type MOD with provider net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.MinecraftLocator@26dcd8c0
> [07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Found duplicate mods:
> Mod ID: 'rubidium' from mod files: rubidium-mc1.20.1-0.7.1a.jar, embeddium-0.3.4+mc1.20.1.jar
> [07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Failed to build unique mod list after mod discovery.
> net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.EarlyLoadingException: Duplicate mods found
> at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.UniqueModListBuilder.buildUniqueList(UniqueModListBuilder.java:87) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar:1.0]
> at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModDiscoverer.discoverMods(ModDiscoverer.java:106) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar:?]
> at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.beginModScan(FMLLoader.java:164) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar:1.0]
> at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.beginScanning(FMLServiceProvider.java:86) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar:1.0]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.runScan(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:112) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$runScanningTransformationServices$8(TransformationServicesHandler.java:100) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1779) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[?:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.runScanningTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:102) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:55) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:88) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:78) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?]
> at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:141) ~[bootstraplauncher-1.1.2.jar:?]
> [07:21:05] [main/ERROR]: Mod Discovery failed. Skipping dependency discovery.

i put together a minecraft java ed 1.20.1 modpack on the curseforge launcher, containing the mods listed in the above crash log. the game crashed 4-5 times despite me trying to disable the mods that i had predicted may be problematic.

i got the modlist from the below link:

https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/11ovdb3/is_there_a_mod_pack_similar_to_fabulously/

which is reasonably self explanatory, but maybe it's something to do with the fact that i'm trying to use v 1.20.1 rather than 1.19.2 that's causing my issues?

i wanted to use 1.20.1 because the terrain gen is much better imo than 1.19.2, and i wanted to use forge rather than fabric because it has quite a few really nice mods that fabric doesn't.

it returned an 'error code 1' report which is very common in modded minecraft (i'm playing the java edition for clarity).

the crash log above is what the game spits out when it's having a bad time.

these mods are created to run on the forge modloader, as opposed to fabric, which is the other popular mod loader.

i have roughly 7440 kb of a 8000 kb GPU allocated to it, which should be neither here nor there. i tried bringing it up from around 6200 to 7440 to no avail. i really didn't think this would sort the issue out but hey, computers can be fickle beasts. it didn't work ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by removing the canary mod.

I ran into the same issue as you and after adding mods one by one, the problem was the canary mod.